# My Manager (Department head) not working during office hours?

Tags: work-environment, team, manager

In my department, my manager is the whole responsible for our team.
In this case, he is very lazy to do work and even he is not interested to see his files.And simply he pass the files/jobs to us. Even though we people have no proper knowledge of the mangers level of work.But we were done that job in appropriate time by breaking our heads and hand over to him. Then he will submit that to higher management. But while we are doing his  works he will not listen to us / help us, simply he will spent the time in Facebook, Entertainment sites / talking with his friends in phone about useless things. These made us very irritated and also very annoyed. So, How should we handle this situation. Main thing is we cant able to contact higher management without his knowledge.

Comment: What is your question here?  Or are you just wanting to complain?

Answer (score 3):

Rarely do you want to go over someone's head, but I think this is warranted here.  Your whole team should ask for a meeting with his direct supervisor.  The purpose of this meeting will be to talk about your concerns regarding this manager.  Be as factual as possible and explain your frustration.  Explain how you are all working hard, but not getting the support you need.  Explain how you want to do good work, but your manager is preventing you from doing this or doing it efficiently.

Have a specific remedy in mind (i.e. firing individual, talking with individual, whatever, your teams feels is the appropriate remedy here.)

I think the key here is going to be going as a team.  If you go as an individual then reprisal against you is more likely.  Firing the whole team will not likely be an option, because then the manager will have to hire a new team and do all the teams work in the mean time.

If you do see reprisal from the manager, you will need to speak with his direct supervisor again.  Once again, the whole team needs to go together for this.

Comment: This is solid advice but I will add to it by saying come in with very specific examples. If you have to wait a week for the meeting so you can sit there and watch him do silly things while you take note of them, then do that. If you go in with shaky details and vague examples you run the risk of his manager thinking you are waisting time yourself. It sounds like you have some good examples but make sure to note exactly what he was doing, for how long, and when.

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately a common problem and a very tough one to fix. There are a few solutions,

1. Confront him, if the whole team feels this way and the whole team confronts him he may change his behavior. This is risky especially if he has the power to fire you. Although in most places they cant actually fire you without just cause (which this is not), however he may be able to make things very difficult for you.
2. Reach out to HR, chances are your company has a policy on facebook/entertainment site use in the office and chances are he is violating it. If you have an IT department that has half a brain they are tacking his account and can easily show what sites he accessed and possibly for how long. You can often reach out to HR anonymously thus he will never know it was you.
3. Go to his superior, you say you cannot do this with out him knowing. Can you send his boss an email? Can you set up a meeting with his boss with out him knowing?
4. Don't do the work, this is most likely the wrong answer but if you are not responsible for the work and doing it only because you feel obligated and cant get in trouble by any one else other than this guy for not doing it, then don't. This will make him look bad when he is in a meeting, asked for the work and cant produce it especially if its his work to do.

If it were me I would go with option 2 for a few reasons. First off if the issue is as serious as you say chances are HR will be involved at some point even if just as a mediator. Getting them involved from the start allows there to be be some accountability so that it is not a he said she said situation. HR also tends to have courses of action for this and can help to get in touch with the proper manager through the correct channels. If his boss may just blow off a meeting with you because you are lower in the company HR will help add some weight to the situation. If for anything it shows that you took the correct course of action from the start, you did not go around anyones back and you made an effort to seek out the proper solution though the right channels. If HR fails then you can move to other means.

Comment: Which of these should the op do? Why?

Comment: I would start out with #2 as they tend to know what to do even if they are not the right people to talk to they will offer the best option for them at this particular company.

Comment: That should be part of your answer and it should explain why...

Answer (score 2):

I may have an unconventional answer, but my answer to you is HELP HIM. It's not your concern how he does his job. Or to complain about him. Your concern is how you do your job and how you help him to achieve his goals and help him to look good to his boss. That's your role. Not to tell him to be different. But to help him achieve his goals. That's what you are there for.It might not seem fair, but that's life. Some people just seem to have things too cushy. But if you try to change their cushy life you will get resistance and not make any friends. That's not progress, that's not getting ahead without hurting others, which is what you ideally should want to do - get ahead without hurting others. Just help him, set the envy aside and things will work out well for you.

Comment: Everytime I have had a bad boss who didn't do his job, it gave me a chance to really shine by doing work way above my level in the organization. Don't worry, the other managers will notice he isn't pulling his weight and notice that you are more than pulling yours. This kind of situation can be the fast track to a promotion.